# Populate a list view in asp.net winform by using stored procedure with parameters through a button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures

In my Winforms application, I have to do search by using three parameters. I retrieve from the database by using stored procedure. But an exception is thrown:

> Procedure or function 'sp_searchProduct' expects parameter '@categoryId', which was not supplied

Kindly help me.

This is my code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-U1OP1S9\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PaintStores;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_searchProduct", con);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categoryId", comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@typeId", comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productId", comboBox3.SelectedValue.ToString());

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dataTable);

    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow drow = dataTable.Rows[i];

        if (drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["ProductId"].ToString());
            lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["ProductName"].ToString());
            lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["TypeName"].ToString());
            lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["Quantity"].ToString());
            lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["Price"].ToString());
            lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["Stock"].ToString());

            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_searchProduct]
    @categoryId INT,
    @typeId INT,
    @productId INT
AS
    IF (@categoryId = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @categoryId = NULL
    END

    IF (@typeId = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @typeId = NULL
    END

    IF (@productId = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @productId = NULL
    END
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT p.ProductId, p.ProductName, p.Quantity, p.Price, p.Stock
    FROM tblProductNew p
    INNER JOIN tblTypes t ON t.TypeId = p.TypeId
    WHERE p.ProductId = ISNULL(@productId, p.ProductId) 
      AND p.TypeId = ISNULL(@typeId, p.TypeId) 
      AND t.MainCategoryId = ISNULL(@categoryId, t.MainCategoryId)
END
```

Comment: May I Have your SP?

Comment: I included it in my question

Comment: @Chirag I corrected the mistakes you have mentioned, and the exception is gone now. But it didn't give the answer to the query. It displays the whole set of data in the list. I debug the line "listView1.Items.Add(lvi);". It give the query list. But in the view the whole data is displayed. Kindly help me.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you add this to your code before calling `da.Fill(dataTable);`

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Your final code should look something like this..

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-U1OP1S9\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PaintStores;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_searchProduct", con);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categoryId",comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Comment: It works. The exception is gone now. But it didn't give the answer to the query. It displays the whole set of data in the list.

Comment: @Coderstech Must be something wrong with the values you pass or the logic in the stored procedure. I suggest you to debug and see what values are being passed to proc.

Comment: I debug it. the line "listView1.Items.Add(lvi);" gives only the query results. But in the view all the data are displayed

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes. One is you should specify command type. Second is, SP expects categoryId as int and you're converting it into string.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-U1OP1S9\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PaintStores;Integrated Security=True");

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_searchProduct", con);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categoryId", comboBox1.SelectedValue);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@typeId", comboBox2.SelectedValue);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productId", comboBox3.SelectedValue);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dataTable);
```

Comment: I corrected them, and the exception is gone now. But it didn't give the answer to the query. It displays the whole set of data in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is I missed to clear the earlier results in the list view. I use the line `listView1.Items.Clear();` before I insert the queried results to the list view. Now the error gone.